# PHP Upload Script not Functioning Properly with New Host

Tags: php, file-upload, hosting, chmod, mkdir

I have set up a php script which creates a directory and uploads a file to that directory.  My issue is that when I use the script to create the directory, the file will not upload entirely.  I ran the exact same script on a different host and the upload process works just fine.  Plus, if I manually create the upload directory and apply chmod 777 via ftp then the transfer works just fine.  Could there be some sort of a setting with the hosting provider that needs to be altered to allow the function to work just right?

Here is the upload form:

```
<form action="/uploadFile.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="img_preview">Preview Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="img_preview" id="img_preview" />
<br />

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="newDirectory" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Flyer" />
</form>
```

Here is my PHP script (uploadFile.php):

```
$thisdir = getcwd(); 
$new_dir = $_POST['id'];
$full_dir = $thisdir . "/upload/" . $new_dir;

function chk_dir($full_dir) {
if(is_dir($full_dir)) {
    echo 'welcome back';
} else {
    return mkdir($full_dir);
}

}
chk_dir($full_dir);
chmod($full_dir, 0777);
?>

<?php
//upload image

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["img_preview"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {

  }
  //set image restrictions
?> 

<?php
if ((($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["img_preview"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["img_preview"]["size"] < 80000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["img_preview"]["error"] > 0)
    {
echo "Please only upload an image for previewing (jpg or gif)...<br>
Also, check to         make     sure the filesize is less than 8MB" .          $_FILES["img_preview"]["error"] .     "<br />";
}
  else
{

//check the image into new directory
if (file_exists("upload/". $new_dir ."/". $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"]))
  {
  echo "It seems that " . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"] . " already exists.";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_preview"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_POST['id'] . "/" . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"]);
  echo "image file has transferred successfully!";
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file please contact for assistance.";
  }
?>
```

Also, when I run the script no errors are produced and the file echos "image file has transferred successfully!" but then when I check for the file in the new location it is completely void.  Thank you for your time in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your question already contains the answer(the upload works when you create the directory via FTP).

I guess the new server has safe_mode enabled, so it will check the UID of the fileowners on file-operations.

What happens:

1. your script creates a directory, owner will be the **webserver**
2. your script(owner of the script usually is the ftp-user) tries to chmod the directory

the script(owner:ftp) cannot chmod the directory(owner:webserver) , because the UIDs are different.

solution: use [ftp_mkdir()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mkdir.php) for creation of directories.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the answer that best represents my issue.  I tried using the ftp_mkdir() function but this also does not seem to work (even when I try a simplified version of the function).  I am going to contact the host about the safe_mode option and see if that enables the ftp_mkdir or mkdir to work right.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your script has a security hole. Never use passed $_POST data to create system directories. And never use 0777 for anything.

The move_uploaded_file() returns false on a failure and you would still get your success message even if it failed (in your code)

Turn on display_errors and error logging and try again.

Comment: "Never use passed $_POST data to create system directories." I am using the $_POST data to associate a directory with the user.  Are you suggesting that I should do this in a previous step?  Or rather are you suggesting that I identify the $_POST data as a separate value, i.e. $newvalue = $_POST['id'];   "And never use 0777 for anything."  How can I go about allowing site users to upload to the directory if the directory is not 777?

Comment: I understand that but $_POST can be modified at at time, you need to have users register, validate their username (alphanumeric, under etc characters) before you store their data in the database and once they are uploading image you need to make sure the current session is valid and use data from the database (that you already filtered in registration step).

Answer (score 0):

you have used `move_uploaded_file()` independently. If it returns false then also `sucsess` message will be printed.

Try

```
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_preview"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_POST['id'] . "/" . $_FILES["img_preview"]["name"])) {
echo "sucess";
}else{
echo "fail";
}
```

After that you will get what is the main problem. Also use debugging point by 
`print_r($_FILES)` before `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: "Also use debugging point by print_r($_FILES) before move_uploaded_file()" Could you please elaborate on this step?  Are you suggesting that I print the file information on the page before moving the files so that I can visually see their location?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer to your question, but still it's worth your attention, I hope. Don't rely on the type of the file sent via `$_FILES`, this is just the mime-type sent by the browser as far as I remember, it can be easily compromized. Use `getimagesize()` function to get true image type as well as height/width.

Same goes for the source file name, but that shouldn't pose a security hole.